# How to fetch values to select/option tags from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, fetch

I have to fetch values to html **option** tag with PHP, but instead of fetching names in options I am fetching them in new select tag

[image]

Instead the names have to be part of the options in select tag

Here is the fetch:

```
 <?php  
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `agents`") or die(mysqli_error());
    while($fetch = $query->fetch_array()){
    ?>
   <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
   <option selected>Agent</option>
   <option ><?php echo $fetch['firstName']?><?php echo $fetch['lastName']?></option>

    </select>
      <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: You have an error. [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do next:

```
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Agent</option>
    <?php  
        $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `agents`");
        if ($query) {
            while($fetch = $query->fetch_array()) {
                echo "<option>" . $fetch['firstName'] . " " .$fetch['lastName'] . "</option>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```